# Inserting Include in Database Content

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with PHP and MySQL and am displaying an article stored in a database by echoing $Content. I would like to include another file just before the second paragraph, which begins with [p]In fact, you (I replaced the paragraph tags with brackets here.)

This doesn't work...

```
$BaseINC = '../../Geobop';
$Content = str_replace('<p>In fact, you', ''.require_once($BaseINC."/$MyPHP/inc/A/Test.php").'',     $Content);
```

It displays the error Warning: require_once(../../Geobop/2B/inc/A/Test.php

In fact, you) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: If I change A/Test.php) to A/Test.php;) (adding a semi-colon), it fails again.

If I strip out the string I'm trying to replace, it works to a point.

```
$BaseINC = '../../Geobop';
$Content = str_replace('<p>In fact, you', ''.require_once($BaseINC."/$MyPHP/inc/A/Test.php").'',     $Content);
```

The weird thing is, it replaces **[p]In fact, you** with a numeral **1**, with the text I inserted in my test file (Test.php) displaying at the top of the page.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I should also mention that Test.php is physically located on one website (MySite1), while the article I'm previewing is on another site. However, all my websites include files stored on MySite1. I've included thousands of files; I just haven't figured out how to do it with a str_replace operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to require the page, but rather want the contents in a string, right? In that case, you should use [`file_get_contents($filename)`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) instead. This returns a string, which can be used as an argument for [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace). [`require`](http://www.php.net/require) returns 1 if there was no error. It does not return its contents(!); unless it is explicitly returned from that file using a `return statement`.

Turning it into:

```
$BaseINC = '../../Geobop';
$Content = str_replace('<p>In fact, you', file_get_contents($BaseINC."/$MyPHP/inc/A/Test.php"), $Content);
```

Using `require` or `include` does not give you their contents in a string. Instead it runs the code inside of it. If that is PHP, it is executed. If it is HTML, it is outputted. This is why you saw the string appear at the top of your page.

Comment: Actually, that might just fix half of my problem. It works in that I can now include "static content." But is there a way I can include PHP content? In other words, if I type TEST on my test file (Test.php), then use file_get_contents, it displays "TEST." But if I type TEST followed by an echo value, it doesn't display the echo value. Getting the contents of files is helpful, but there are several fairly complex includes, with lots of PHP code, I'd like to include here.

Comment: well, in that case you'd need to have the file parsed first. Often this can be done by calling it via a http-request, like so: `file_get_contents('http://localhost/Test.php')` instead of like `file_get_contents('./Test.php')`.