# How can I use file_get_contents without losing echo values?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's begin with an article on a static page (Test.php) that includes another file full of PHP code (Code.php). Some of the echo values on Code.php are declared on a third file higher up the food chain (Values.php).

Everything works fine - until I take the article out of Test.php, insert it in a database and display it by echoing $Content. Now my include doesn't work, since you can't put PHP includes inside a database. (Or maybe you can, but it's apparently next to impossible, and everyone screams DON'T DO IT!)

I just learned how to use file_get_contents:

```
$Content = str_replace('<p id="1"', '.file_get_contents($BaseINC."/inc/Test.php").'<p id="1">', $Content);
```

It works great, except that it only displays static text - no PHP code.

Then I learned how to parse the file, like this:

```
file_get_contents("http://MySite/Test.php")
```

It works better. I can echo $Something, as long as $Something is defined in Test.php...

```
$Something = 'Cool!';
echo $Something;
```

The problem is that all the echo values that are defined on a separate file (e.g. Values.php) no longer work, apparently because I've removed Test.php from the flow. Is there a way to somehow reconnect Test.php with Code.php so those echo values will regain their values? Or is there some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

For whatever it's worth, most of the missing values are created by a database query. One workaround is to recreate the values based on each page's URL. The irony is that all the scripts I've tried for displaying page URL don't even work; instead, they display the path to Test.php. So I'm really confused.

Comment: you should be using include() or require() to execute local php files.. not file_get_contents.

Comment: Hmmm...that's what I was asking about @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692448/inserting-include-in-database-content I couldn't figure out why my include wasn't working, but I was told to use file_get_contents instead.

Comment: I may have mis-understood then and probably just confused you further. See if my answer makes any sense.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom people can tell you lots of things on SO, that doesn't mean they're right.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to illustrate the different ways of including a php file:

```
<?php
//Test.php
$bar = 'orange'; echo $bar;
```

---

```
<?php
// Example.php
echo file_get_contents("Test.php") // $bar = 'orange'; echo $bar;
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/Test.php") // orange
// Probably not correct, big security risk https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection
include("Test.php") // orange
```

Comment: `include()` is the correct way, `file_get_contents()` is varying levels of incorrect.

Comment: OK, I think I see one of my problems. I think I'm including it correctly...except that I don't know how to put on the brakes. This is a portion of my code: '.require_once($BaseINC."/2B/inc/C/Child/Aux_Scripts/GZ/Series.php").'<div>' The error interprets the include path as GZ/Series.php <div>. But when I put a semi-colon after Series.php), I get a syntax error.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, added a note about remote code injection.

Comment: Not only that, but because it's a separate invocation you lose access to client GET/POST/SESSION/COOKIE information, SERVER no longer reflects the client request, and you're also introducing more webserver delay/resource usage overhead as it has to process these extra requests.